# Why does openssl rsautl on Mac and raspberry pi produce different results?

Tags: openssl, raspberry-pi, macos-high-sierra

I am currently trying to encrypt a file on a raspberry pi (a) and then decrypt the file on a Mac (b).

The command I am running to encrypt the file on (a) is

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -in [FILE] -out [ENC_FILE]
```

The command I am running to decrypt the file on (b) is

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in [ENC_FILE] -out [DEC_FILE]
```

However when I run the second command I get the error:

```
bad decrypt
140736032883756:error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.200.3/libressl-2.6/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:533:
```

When I attempt this with two Macs, it works fine.

My Mac is running **High Seirra** with openssl version

```
LibreSSL 2.6.4
```

My Raspberry Pi is running **Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)** with openssl version

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
```

Looking further into this, I encrypted the same file which contained the text *hello* on both machines with the same password (using -nosalt). Here is the output:

a)

```
00000000  f6 b2 6f c7 2b 2c 8d ea  be 83 5f b1 53 9f 65 91  |..o.+,...._.S.e.|
00000010
```

b)

```
00000000  cc b7 e4 68 ee 8d 38 65  3b 5e ab 98 5d 09 18 95  |...h..8e;^..]...|
00000010
```

Comment: Why are you saying that the problem occurs with `aes-256-cbc` while you are are giving RSA command?

Comment: I mean the problem is not RSA specific. the same problem occurs when trying to encrypt or decrypt with an AES  cypher between the two machines

Comment: Try `-in '[ENCRYPTED RANDOM STRING]'` instead of `-in [ENCRYPTED RANDOM STRING]` and see if it helps? Also can you post an example encrypted string

Comment: @TarunLalwani see the edited question text^^

Comment: Could this be related to the default switch in OpenSSL 1.1 ? They swapped from MD5 as default to SHA, and I think this breaks backwards compatibility with other frameworks. Has something to do with the derived key generated by the framework for the encryption.